# Difference between "next dev" and "npm run dev"

Tags: node.js, next.js

Wondering if there is any difference between running

```
next dev
```

or

```
npm run dev
```

In VScode, with a fresh installation I get warnings using next, but no warning using npm. The warnings I get are of this kind:

```
(node:76504) ExperimentalWarning: stream/web is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
```

EDIT: Next.j 13.5.6 and node v18.18.2

Answer (score 2):

`next dev` is a command specific to Next.js framework and it is used to start Next.js app in development mode.

`npm run dev` is a command used to run Node.js application in development mode. The effect of the script `npm run dev` can be specified in package.json (created when initializing the Nodejs app with npm init)

For Next.js apps it is common to specify running the dev mode with the script:

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev"
}
```

So in that case `npm run dev` literally executes `next dev`.

**WHEN IT COMES TO THE WARNING:**

It simply informs you that the Node version you are using has some experimental features.

It shouldn't be something to worry about much because it shouldn't affect the functionality of your application but keep in mind that those experimental modules may change.

You can choose to ignore it or check for updates to Node.js or the specific modules causing the warning if it becomes problematic.

Comment: The node version I used is the v18.18.2, which currently is LTS. Can LTS versions have experimental features?

Comment: @iosonosempreio LTS version means Long-Time Support -  they are designed to be stable, reliable, provide backwards compatibility and don't include any breaking changes.
Therefore it is unusual to encounter experimental features in LTS version. 
That warning message is likely to related to some specific package or library your project is using.
If you want to "find the mole" you should dig deeper into node_modules.
I can't really help you with finding that odd package unless you provide me (or us as anyone watching the thread) the source code with that "stream/web feature".

Comment: Of course LTS versions can have experimental features like every other version. The thing is just the by default these are not enabled. Experimental features can be enabled specifically as needed, and then this generates a warning too.